# Removing Duplicate Item Entries on a Calendar SP 2010

Tags: filter, calendar, duplicate, unique

My calendar is currently set up where it shows all new items added to the list for the past 30 days.

This works perfectly for the function I need, however, the only problem is that it does not omit duplicate entries of the same name.

So for example say I have 6 item entries of the same name with other data that is not relevant to the display and only want 1 of them to show up in a given calendar slot per day. Is there any way to do this simply?

Comment: The calendar is not as such where it is used for events, but rather as a tracker for recently added items to the list. My plan is to embed this on the homepage of the site for a quick view of what's been added recently. The recently modified items web part worked before but would not display the right information I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and write an Item Adding Event Receiver to check if the item exist. And if it does, prevent the list from being updated

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra field to the calendar list. For example a boolean field with the name ShowInSummary. Modify the calendar list items and set the field ShowInSummary to True for the items you would like to show in the summary list. Create a Content Query Webpart.  Configure this Content Query Webpart that is going to use the Calendar list. Add also a filter that it needs to show only the list items where field ShowInSummary is True.